# Outlook keyboard shortcut to move message to a different folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to organize my inbox and move my messages to certain folders. Is there a keyboard shortcut I can set up like:

CRTL + 1 : Personal Folder

CRTL + 2 : Task 1 Folder

CRTL + 3 : Task 2 Folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a macro, digital certificate, and assign it to a toolbar button or keyboard shortcut.  Check out the information listed here:

http://www.fiftyfoureleven.com/weblog/general/outlook-email-shortcuts

**Here's the macro code:**

```
Sub MoveSelectedMessagesToFolder()
On Error Resume Next


    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, objInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace, objItem As Outlook.MailItem


    Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objInbox = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set objFolder = objInbox.Folders("_Reviewed")
    'Assume this is a mail folder


    If objFolder Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "This folder doesn't exist!", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "INVALID FOLDER"
    End If


    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
        'Require that this procedure be called only when a message is selected
        Exit Sub
    End If


    For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If objFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
            If objItem.Class = olMail Then
                objItem.Move objFolder
            End If
        End If
    Next


    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objInbox = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This is all nice, but it does not work in Outlook 2007.

Oh, the macro works just fine, but there is no way I can assign any keyboard shortcut to run the macro...

Comment: I'd be interested in how to do it in 2007 too

Comment: You could use an AutoHotKey macro to run them, couldn't you?

Comment: I couldn't see any info on "AutoHotKey" macros in Outlook 2007.  I created a new question re Outlook 2007 here: http://superuser.com/questions/132066/outlook-2007-keyboard-shortcut-to-move-message-to-a-different-folder

Answer (score 16):

Yes - you can create a [Quick Step](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/automate-common-or-repetitive-tasks-with-quick-steps-HA010370689.aspx) to easily do this. Create one to move items to a folder, select options, and assign a shortcut (which can be CTRL + SHIFT 1-9).

[image: Create a new quick step]

[image: Select quick step options]

[image: Select quick step shortcut]