# How do you define your own shortcuts in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2007

In previous versions of Outlook it was possbile to write some VBA and assign a shortcut to do this.  I can't see how to do this in 2007, if indeed it is possbile.

*Note - the following thread is relevant but only for earlier versions
[Outlook keyboard shortcut to move message to a different folder](https://superuser.com/questions/92688/outlook-keyboard-shortcut-to-move-message-to-a-different-folder)*

Comment: check this question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57075/how-do-i-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-a-vba-macro-in-outlook-2007

Comment: Ah - I didnt think of looking on SO - it seemed more of a SU sort of thing.  Thanks for the info.