# Outlook 2007 keyboard shortcut to move message to a different folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to setup a shortcut in Outlook 2007 to move messages to a given folder?

There is a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/92688/outlook-keyboard-shortcut-to-move-message-to-a-different-folder) but it appears the accepted answer doesn't work in Outlook 2007.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine an AutoHotKey macro could do this for you. Take a look at [this discussion from the AutoHotKey forums](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic41790.html) about "Archiving email in Outlook with a single keystroke".

Answer (score 1):

It's been some time, but since I found this question in my searching before I found the eventual solution, I thought I'd share here.

[This page](http://www.noprobo.com/posts/outlook-custom-move-shortcuts) has a pretty well documented procedure that worked for me. The only modification needed is the section about "Macro Security" did not quite match up to my options. The author suggests using "Medium" security, while I was presented a different set of choices. "Warnings for all macros" appears to work although there is technically a small security risk if you are changing it from one of the more paranoid settings. Check with your company IT if you are concerned.

After posting this I noticed that the macro had issues with signed emails unless the macro itself is signed. Thankfully [another helpful person](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/digitally-sign-a-macro-project-HA001231781.aspx#BM12) has pretty decent instructions on how to do that.

Comment: The link seems to be broken ...

Answer (score 0):

Move an item.   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

More shortcuts for Outlook can be found here:
[**Keyboard shortcuts for Outlook**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/keyboard-shortcuts-for-outlook-HP001230396.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It might not be 100% straightforward but if you add a command to your ribbon/toolbar and then right click the button while the add command dialog is still open, you can rename the button.

If you start the name as &1 and then you change the display option for that button to show the text, then hitting alt+1 will trigger the command.

This will work with any command/digit combo but you have to have the text visible to work as it's just exploiting the menu/alt key interactions.

Comment: May be your answer should be in steps to make it easily understandable

Comment: Going into a meeting but will try to beef up the answer later. Redid the formatting to include the paragraph breaks I thought I had included when typing it up.